# How to group two windows into one?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I need to insert the window with the tabbed called "First panel, Second panel, Third panel, Fourth panel" into the window named "Animation".
What should I do so that at the end it looks like: a window that has an animation box with four tabs, a Text box and a User input box?

**First class called "Main" :**

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Demo");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JLabel square1 = new JLabel("Animation");
    JLabel square2 = new JLabel("Text");
    JTextField square3 = new JTextField("User Input");

    public Main() {
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2,3,3));
        panel.add(square1);
        panel.add(square2);
        panel.add(square3); 
        frame.add(panel);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(600,400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Tabbed tp = new Tabbed();       
        tp.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        tp.setSize(600,400);
        tp.setVisible(true);

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Main();         
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**'Second class called "Tabbed" :'**

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Tabbed extends JFrame{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    JPanel firstPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel secondPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel thirdPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel fourPanel = new JPanel();

    JLabel firstLabel = new JLabel("First!");
    JLabel secondLabel = new JLabel("Second!");
    JLabel thirdLabel = new JLabel("Third!");
    JLabel fourLabel = new JLabel("Fourth!");

    JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();

    public Tabbed(){
        firstPanel.add(firstLabel);
        secondPanel.add(secondLabel);
        thirdPanel.add(thirdLabel);
        fourPanel.add(fourLabel);

        tabbedPane.add("First panel",firstPanel);
        tabbedPane.add("Second panel",secondPanel);
        tabbedPane.add("Third panel",thirdPanel);
        tabbedPane.add("Fourth panel",fourPanel);

        add(tabbedPane);
    }
}
```

Here's how I want to combine the two windows :

[image]

Comment: Here's how I want to combine the two windows : https://imgur.com/3KWfjtA

Comment: Don't extend JFrame. Extend JPanel. Then you can add the panel to the main frame. That is a GUI should be designed with a single JFrame and then you add panels containing child components to the frame.

Comment: Okay , I've modified the "public class Tabbed extends JPanel{" but can you show me which panel I have to modify ?

Comment: A [BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/BorderLayout.html) can accomplish the layout in your image.

Comment: @VGR *"A BorderLayout can accomplish the layout.."* Indeed! That tabbed pane in the center, `Text `label at the `LINE_END` and `User Input` at `PAGE_END` .. done.

Comment: Nice ! I've got something not bad, thank you a lot guys !

Comment: *"thank you a lot guys !"* Tip: Add @VGR (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.